# How to chain 2 API calls with redux thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm making a weather app, which detects your current location's coordinates by making an API call to freegeoip.com, then takes those coordinates to make an API call to openweathermap.org to fetch your current location's weather.

How would I do this with redux thunk?

This is my current action creator code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_CURRENT_CITY = 'FETCH_CURRENT_CITY';

const API_KEY = '95108d63b7f0cf597d80c6d17c8010e0';
const ROOT_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export function fetchCurrentCityCoords() {
  const request = axios.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/');

  console.log('Request coords:', request);

  return (dispatch) => {
    request.then(({response}) => {
      dispatch(fetchCurrentCityWeather(response));
    });
  };
}

export function fetchCurrentCityWeather(coords) {
  const lat = coords.data.latitude;
  const lon = coords.data.longitude;

  const url = `${ROOT_URL}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  console.log('Request weather:', request);

  return (dispatch) => {
    request.then(({response}) => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_CURRENT_CITY,
        payload: response
      })
    });
  };
}
```

Console logs:

```
Request coords: Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
    at fetchCurrentCityWeather (bundle.js:26131)
    at bundle.js:26125
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the API `response` holds a `data` property?
try debugging the first line of `fetchCurrentCityWeather` function and check what `coords` holds, or just try `console.log(coords);` to see it's object structure.

maybe this:

```
 const lat = coords.data.latitude;
 const lon = coords.data.longitude;
```

should be like that:

```
 const lat = coords.latitude;
 const lon = coords.longitude;
```

**Edit**
following your comment,
for debug purpose try editing your `fetchCurrentCityWeather` function to this code and see what is printed to the console:

```
export function fetchCurrentCityWeather(coords) {
    console.log(coords);

  //const lat = coords.data.latitude;
  //const lon = coords.data.longitude;

  //const url = `${ROOT_URL}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`;
  //const request = axios.get(url);

  //console.log('Request weather:', request);

  //return (dispatch) => {
    //request.then(({response}) => {
     // dispatch({
        //type: FETCH_CURRENT_CITY,
       // payload: response
      //})
    //});
 // };
}
```

**EDIT #2**
following your comment, you are getting `undefined` hence you can't use `.map` on it. this is your answer to the error.
As for why you are getting `undefined`, i think it's because this block of code:

```
 return (dispatch) => {
    request.then(({response}) => {
      dispatch(fetchCurrentCityWeather(response));
    });
  };
```

You are doing "Destructuring" to the `response` parameter with this `{response}`.
try this instead:

```
 return (dispatch) => {
    request.then((response) => {
      dispatch(fetchCurrentCityWeather(response));
    });
  };
```

Comment: I had the same suspicion too and unfortunately it still doesnt work. This is the console log message i get: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
    at fetchCurrentCityWeather (bundle.js:26132)
    at bundle.js:26126`

Comment: Commented out as you suggested and this is what console shows: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
    at dispatch (bundle.js:20476)
    at bundle.js:26418
    at dispatch (bundle.js:21229)
    at bundle.js:26126`

Comment: yeah this is expected as you are not returning a valid `Action` object but what about the `console.log(coords);` line, it didn't print the value of `coords`?

Comment: comes back as undefined

Comment: @JosephLiu i've edit my answer again. try to pass `response` without Destructuring it.

Comment: you're right. I was using the new ES6 syntax wrong! It should be ({data}) instead. Now it's working alright. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
>       at fetchCurrentCityWeather (bundle.js:26131)
>       at bundle.js:26125

Problems appears to be your `const lat = coords.data.latitude` it's undefined.

So you have to check if the

```
return (dispatch) => {
request.then(({response}) => {
  dispatch(fetchCurrentCityWeather(response));
});
```

Calls`fetchCurrentCityWeather` with correct `response` object you expect to have properties `data.latitude` & `data.longitude` you seem to incorrectly refer.

### Advise.

`console.log(coords);` inside `fetchCurrentCityWeather` function to see if it has those properties.

Comment: This is what it shows: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
    at dispatch (bundle.js:20476)
    at bundle.js:26418
    at dispatch (bundle.js:21229)
    at bundle.js:26126`

Comment: Okay, what about going one level up? Before dispatching `fetchCurrentCityWeather`, commenting the whole line out. Try to `console.log(response)` there. Is it the object you need? @JosephLiu

Comment: it comes back as undefined `return (dispatch) => {
    request.then(({response}) => {
      console.log('response:',response);
      // dispatch(fetchCurrentCityWeather(response));
    });
  };`

Comment: @JosephLiu Consider Sag1v 's updated answer above. Passing the response without destructuring it.